# Access a variable outside of Excel::load in Laravel-excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to pass a variable to function below. I tried global variable & by reference but the counters keep resetting (as shown in second patch of code).

```
private $counter = 0;

 public function importExcel(Request $request)
 {
   $count = 0
    **some other code**
                try {
                    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(1000, function($reader) use($tableName, $tableColumns, &$count) {
                        var_dump($this->counter);
                        var_dump($count);
                        if ($reader->count() && ($this->counter < 30 || $count < 30)) {
                        $this->counter++;
                        $count++;
                        var_dump('inside: ' . $this->counter . ';' . $count);
                            /** Get uploaded file columns **/
                            $headerRow = $reader->first()->keys()->toArray();

                            /** Check if destination table columns are found in uploaded file **/
                            if (is_array($headerRow) && !array_diff($tableColumns, $headerRow)) {
                                /** Extract only the data we need in destination table from uploaded file **/
                                $data = array_map(function($row) use($tableColumns) {
                                    $arr = [];
                                    foreach ($tableColumns as $column) {
                                        $arr[$column] = $row[$column];
                                    }
                                    return $arr;
                                }, $reader->toArray());

                                /** Insert the data we need to destination table **/
                                DB::connection(*censored*)
                                    ->table($tableName)
                                    ->insert($data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
 }
```

results:

```
int(0)
int(0)
string(11) "inside: 1;1"
int(0)
int(0)
string(11) "inside: 1;1"
int(0)
int(0)
string(11) "inside: 1;1"
int(0)
int(0)
string(11) "inside: 1;1"
int(0)
int(0)
string(11) "inside: 1;1"
etc... etc... etc...
```

Why both counters don't accumulate? How can I get the counters to accumulate? corrections or other solutions are welcomed.